SQL Character Anomaly Detection Error in OWASP CRS with next-auth Callback URL via Google Cloud Armor
I am encountering an error related to the OWASP Core Rule Set (CRS) when working with the next-auth library for authentication in my application. The error message is as follows:
Signature: owasp-crs-v030301-id942421-sqli

Description: Restricted SQL Character Anomaly Detection (cookies): # of special characters exceeded (3)

I believe this issue is related to the next-auth.callback-url, which is set to http%3A%2F%2my_domain_name%2F. The encoded URL seems to be triggering the SQL character anomaly detection rules in OWASP CRS.
Context

Framework: Next.js
Authentication Library: next-auth

How can I properly configure my application to avoid this false positive detection by OWASP CRS while still using the next-auth callback URL?

I suggest you to contact Google to get support for this.
